# Eigen QR decomposition results differs from two methods

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigen, qr-decomposition

I try to use QR decomposition using Eigen, but the results get from the following tow methods is different, please help me to find out the error!
Thanks.

```
// Initialize the sparse matrix
A.setFromTriplets(triplets.begin(), triplets.end());
A.makeCompressed();

//Dense matrix method
MatrixXd MatrixA = A;
HouseholderQR<MatrixXd> qr(MatrixA);
MatrixXd Rr = qr.matrixQR().triangularView<Upper>();

//Sparse matrix method
SparseQR < SparseMatrix < double >, COLAMDOrdering< int > > qr;
qr.compute(A);
SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> Rr = qr.matrixR();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `SparseQR` performs column reordering to both reduce fill-in and achieve a nearly rank-revealing decomposition, similar to `ColPivHouseholderQR`. More precisely, `HouseholderQR` computes: `A = Q*R`, whereas `SparseQR` computes: `A*P = Q*R`. So it is expected that the two `R` triangular factors are different.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, then how shall I get the matrixR?
I try to use:
 Rr = qr.matrixR()*qr.colsPermutation();
But it seems not correct

Comment: You could compute `qr.matrixR()*qr.colsPermutation().inverse()` but the result won't be triangular anymore. I don't known what's your use case, but in most cases you adapt it to explicitly deal with the additional permutation.